# Point on a Line in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point, line, select-by-location

I have multiple points and some of these points are sitting directly on a line which I do not want. You can see the image below. What I need is **"to identify the points sitting on the line"** *I tried using the selection by location (used both intersect, touches boundary and contain) but no result was returned*.

Can someone give me and idea of how to identify these points without having to manually search through over 200000 points and several lines?

[image: Points on lines]

Comment: Try selecting within a distance of.

Comment: @Hornbydd is correct.  If your selection by location didn't return any results, it means that the points are not actually (exactly) on the line (or otherwise you configured the tool incorrectly, but not likely).  It is most likely that the points are very close to the line, but not exactly on it.  So it is up to you to decide what distance to the line is relevant to selecting the points and then try again using that distance.

Comment: It's very unlikely for a point to be *exactly* on a line to double precision, or even a tolerance at the precision of the coordinates (unless you land exactly on a vertex). Within Distance Of is you only card to play here. The good new is this will utilize a spatial index.

Answer (score 3):

Your points are not directly sitting on any lines. They almost never are, due to the precision of coordinates. You need to specify when you consider them coincident. Assuming your units are meters. If a point is considered on a line if it is within 1 mm of a line you would *select by distance* of .001 and so on.

Comment: @Godofsix let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks all for your time. I tried all the methods and no results yet. Maybe there's something I'm not doing right. As soon as something happens I like you all know.

Comment: @Godofsix you can always post a snippet of your data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a buffer of the lines first.  That works too

Comment: Or Points first